# How to get the list of items in a transaction in package arules

Tags: r, arules, market-basket-analysis

I know you can see the content of each transaction using `inspect` and then extract the items yourself, but is there a convenient way to get a list of all items which belong to a transaction?

Comment: It would be easier to help you with a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Maybe you can even include one from the package help pages and make it clear what information you want to extract and how you want to store it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a_list <- list( # Create example data
      c("a","b","c"),
      c("a","b"),
      c("a","b","d"),
      c("c","e"),
      c("a","b","d","e")
      )

## set transaction names
names(a_list) <- paste("Tr",c(1:5), sep = "")
a_list

## coerce into transactions
trans1 <- as(a_list, "transactions")

## analyze transactions
summary(trans1)
image(trans1)  

# if you want an actual list structure:
trans1 <- as(a_list, "list")
```

This is the plot of it from `image()`:

[image]

Now with a bigger `transactions` object:

```
data("Adult")
adult_list <- as(Adult, "list")
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an R package called `data.table` that allow you to do this type of transaction aggregations.

For example:

```
data <- data.frame( 
                  transactionID = c("1001", "1001", "1002", "1003", "1003", "1003"),
                  item= c("A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "C")
                  )
```

One way to get a list of all items which belong to a transaction:

**Aggregate Items By Transaction. Data.table**

[image]

Other way, by the function `split`:

```
data.aggregate <- split(data$item, data$transactionID)
> data.aggregate
$`1001`
[1] A B
Levels: A B C

$`1002`
[1] B
Levels: A B C

$`1003`
[1] A B C
Levels: A B C
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible simple solution if your goal is just to see all of the items contained across all transactions (that is, a complete item list) is the following:

```
unique(unlist(as(a_list, "list")))
```